# Restlet: Post with multiple parameters

Tags: java, rest, restlet

Please take a look at the following example:

```
public interface ILoginResource {

    @Post
    public void login(String username, String password);
}

public class LoginServerResource extends ServerResource implements ILoginResource { 
    @Override
    public void login(String username, String password) {   
        System.out.println("username = " + username);
        System.out.println("password = " + password);
    }   
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClientResource loginResource = new ClientResource(url);
    ILoginResource res = loginResource.wrap(ILoginResource.class);
    res.login("TestUser","TestPassword");
}
```

Output is: 
username = TestPassword  
password = null

What am I doing wrong? Or is it not possible to use multiple parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you expected, it is indeed not possible to pass multiple arguments in a single call, instead, you can introduce a message class like this:

```
public class LoginRequest {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    /**
     * For deserialization.
     */
    public LoginRequest() {
    }

    /**
     * @param username
     *            The user's name
     * @param password
     *            The password
     */
    public LoginRequest(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LoginRequest [username=" + username + ", password=" + password + "]";
    }
}
```

And modify your resource like this:

```
public interface ILoginResource {
    @Post
    public void login(LoginRequest req);
}
```